# Parse xml with jquery and display nodes-node names and node values- on screen

Tags: jquery, xml

Hi all I have the below xml:

```
<root>
     <a>Value</a>
     <b>Value</b>
     <c>Value</c>
</root>
```

is there a way to get the root child elements and display them on screen like this

```
     <a>Value</a>
     <b>Value</b>
     <c>Value</c>
```

?
I know that with text() method I can get only the "Value" part and with .nodeName only the "a" part.What I want is to take the whole

```
     <a>Value</a>
```

.Any ideas would be really appreciated

Comment: Sorry I don't have the option of xslt.I parse the xml response from an ajax call,I extract a part of the xml response  and must display it the way I discribed!#Yes I know I have to accept the ansers but I believe this is not the problem right now! :)

Comment: well, you could make a loop using both text() and .nodeName

Comment: kind of reconstructing the xml from nodeName and text()?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var xml = "<root>
             <a>Value</a>
             <b>Value</b>
             <c>Value</c>
           </root>
          ",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $root = $xml.find( "root" );
```

then maybe like

```
$root.html();
```

You may have to play with that a little to make it give you what you want..but should work

Comment: thanx for answering Evan!Unfortunatelly .html() works only with html and not with xml and $xml.find() didn't quite work!Thanx anyway!